# Android relativelayout lost focus causes lag on touch

Tags: android, android-layout

I've a custom view extended from relativelayout, after adding few imageview, 1 for background, and one for a transparent bitmap from png.
I've successfully setRotation and use setTranslationX and Y on a imageview, and all works fine, until...

when the view itself got lost focus when either I show a popup menu, or show a dialogbox. The imageview got resetted as before rotation and resize, and my on touch event become laggier and laggier as the more time I've tried to make it lost focus.

I tried invalidate on the relativelayout and it does nothing! I'm so close to getting what i needed, and found these super bugs.

I've not use any ondraw, as I know relativelayout does not support it.

Answer (score 0):

I found my own issue, I was using

```
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus)
```

to initialize my imageviews, and lost focus is what is causing the resetup of objects on views which causes the lag and reset of positioning.